# Rmarkdown yaml use of !r

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I hope someone can help me with this problem. I need to run params$Year and params$Dates as R code on my yaml so my `Year: 2012` can be available for the slider `min` and `max`. For example, if I change the `Year` to `Year: 2013` my slider only recognizes the new Year until I manually run `params$Year` in the R console. Short example below:

````
---
title: "Hola"
output:
  pdf_document:
  html_document:
params:
  Year: 2012   #This value is not recognized for min and max below when changed to a different year
  Dates:
    input: slider
    min: !r as.Date(paste0(params$Year,"-01-01"))
    max: !r as.Date(paste0(params$Year,"-06-30"))
    value: !r c(as.Date(paste0(params$Year,"-01-01")), as.Date(paste0(params$Year,"-01-30")))
    step: 15
---

#I tried the code below without success. 
#The main question here is: How can I run params$Year inside my yaml so it can update the 
#slider min and max before the document is knitted. Thanks beforehand.

```yaml
`r params$Year`
`r params$Dates`
```
````

Comment: I don't think you can refer to the contents of `params` within its declaration.  When I tested your code, I got a warning message from `yaml::yaml.load` about an error when handling type 'r', which can be caused by referencing a value that does not exist yet.
Also, the only value passed to params$Dates in your example is the `value` (as plain text, due to the error caused by undefined variables).  If you want a nested list with values derived from other parameters, it might work best to create it in a setup chunk inside the body of the R Markdown document.